# Possessive with nonessential phrase

Tags: possessives

Here's a puzzler: Is the use here of *his wife, Julie's,* correct?

> Peter Brown, still smarting from his wife, Julie's, infidelity, wants
>   her dead, and he's trying to convince his friend Bill to commit the
>   murder.

I don't think so, but it seemed like an interesting case that I haven't seen covered anywhere.

Comment: I believe there have been former questions on this site about this topic. But as far as I know, there isn't any particularly satisfying answer, because the definition of "correct" is pretty complicated and fuzzy.

Comment: The thing is, in making "Julie" an essential clause, it violates rules regarding omitting commas with essential clauses and including them with nonessential -- in other words, implying that Peter has more than one wife. Thanks for the link to the other question, though, sumelic.